# Some sites block my app file type

Tags: iphone

I created my own file type called foo. It is text file.
What I want to do is when user touches file name with extension .foo in Safari, my app is executed. 
But, because it is text file, some sites show that file in text viewer. 
How can I prevent that? It works fine in other sites.
This is what I wrote in my info.plist.

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>myicon.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>my file</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.mycompany.foo</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>

<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>my file</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.mycompany.foo</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>foo</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be to do with the MIME types on the web servers serving the content. There is not much you can do about this unless of course you run the webserver in question.

Hope that helps.